# Find in array the biggest multiple and write it vica versa

Tags: c++

I was given a task:

**it is given an array of five numbers**

**First** - *Find all numbers that are multiples of four*
**Second** - *Find the biggest of them and write it vice versa.*

I have written a code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#define size 12
int main()
{
int new_max=0;
int a1, a2;
int i=0, j=0;
int a, b, c=0;
int u[size]={38,12,36,45,16,46,14,19,54,53,95, 98};
int max=0;
cout<<"Array: \n";
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
cout<<u[i]<<" \n";
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    if (u[i]%4==0)
    {
        cout<<"array "<<u[i]<<" \n";
        for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            if(max<u[i])
            {
                max=u[i];
            }}}}

cout<<"max "<<max<<endl;


 while(max > 0)
{
        new_max = new_max*10 + ( max % 10);
        max = max/10;
}
cout << new_max << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a loop that defines i inside a loop that defines i.  The inside loop will change the value of i and confuse the outside loop.  The two loops need different variables.

Comment: You have: `if(max>u[i])` - looks like you need to reverse the inequality to `<`. Aren't you getting `max 0` as output? Also, you don't need the second `for` loop..

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 5> input = { 36, 12, 38, 45, 16 };
    auto validRangeEnd = std::remove_if(std::begin(input),
                                        std::end(input),
                                        [](int i){ return i % 4 != 0; });
    // Now std::begin(input) -> validRangeEnd contain the ones divisible by 4
    auto max = std::max_element(std::begin(input), validRangeEnd);
    // Max contains the max number from the filtered range
    auto stringMax = std::to_string(*max);
    std::reverse(std::begin(stringMax), std::end(stringMax));
    // Reverse reverses the max number
    std::cout << stringMax;
}
```

By no means optimal but I feel it's useful for educational purposes :).
(Both remove_if and max_elements do a pass so I'll re-examine some stuff that I don't need to but this is a good algorithmic representation of the problem anyway. Also, no loops, look! :))